# angularjs loading a script after app bootsrapped

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to convert a website which is already online.
My issue is that I'm using a jquery function to adjust the dimension of images loaded through a json file.

Unfortunately the script doesn't work coz it seems that it loads before the images are initialized....

The code is in the main view...
I've tried to include the script src in the index but it doesn't work.
I'm also initializing jquery before angular.

here's part of the code i'm using...

```
<div ng-repeat="topdiscount in topdiscounts.prodotti" class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 item-prod text-center">
    <p class='s25' ng-if=" topdiscount.prezzo_f == topdiscount.prezzos_f" class="md-xs-3" ><b>{{topdiscount.prezzo_f | currency}}</b></p>
    <p class='text-center' ng-if="topdiscount.prezzo_f = prodott.prezzos_f">
        <p class='line-through inline'><b>{{topdiscount.prezzo_f | currency}}</b></p>
        <p class='red s25 m-s-left inline'><b> {{topdiscount.prezzos_f | currency}}</b></p><br class='on_mobile'>
        <p class='sconto'>SCONTO 
            <span class='price-prod'>{{topdiscount.sconto_f}}%</span>
        </p>
    </p>
    <a class='link-prod' href="#/p/{topdiscount.id}}/{{topdiscount.nome_t | encodeUri}}" target="_blank"></a>
    <div class='social_share clearfix'>
        <p class='inline'> 
            <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=#/p/{topdiscount.id}}/{{topdiscount.nome_t | encodeUri}}"  media="{{topdiscount.immagine_t | encodeUri}}" description="buymadesimple.com: {{topdiscount.nome_t | encodeUri}}" data-pin-do='buttonPin' target='_blank' data-pin-config='above'>
                <img  alt='pin it' title='pin it' src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png">
            </a>
        </p>
        <p class='inline'>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wishButton" data-refid="{topdiscount.id}}"><i id="i-{topdiscount.id}}"  class='fa fa-heart-'></i></a><!-- $iclass -->
        </p>
    </div>    
    <div class='img_container image-container'>
        <img class="prod_image" data-scale="best-fit-down" data-align="center" src="{{topdiscount.immagine_t}}" title="{{topdiscount.nome_t}}" alt="{{topdiscount.nome_t}}">
    </div>
        <p class='title-prod'><b>{{topdiscount.marca_t}}</b></p>
        <p class='name-prod'>{{topdiscount.nome_t}}</p><hr>
        <p class='market'>From {{topdiscount.shop_t}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="scripts/js/image.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("img.prod_image").imageScale();
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure I've explained it properly...but I hope you can help me out...
Thank you!

Comment: you'll have to wrap the jquery code in a directive that can execute when the directive is initialized, rather than on page load.  there are plenty of examples of this on this site and others as well.

Comment: honestly, it doesn't sound like you would even need this JQuery function, you should be able to scale the images through an angular function.  Can you elaborate on what the `.imageScale()` function actually does, so an appropriate angular replacement can be demonstrated?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....needed to use a directive...

```
angular.module('myApp') .directive('myScript', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<img class="prod_image" data-scale="best-fit-down" data-align="center" src="{{img}}" title="{{name}}" alt="{{nome}}"></div>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $("img.prod_image").imageScale(); 
      }
  };
```

});

And then in the `main.html`:

```
    <div my-script class='img_container image-container'>
                    </div>
...
 <script src="scripts/js/image.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And calling the directive in `index.html`

```
<script src="scripts/directives/myScript.js"></script>
```

Thanks anyway!!